# Tidy can’t use matches with recurse 0, false, or undef

Tags: puppet

I have the following Puppet resource.

```
tidy {
    'beat_lock':
      age  => '8h',
      path    => '/var/lib/beat/',
      alias   => 'beat_lock',
      matches => 'run.lock',
      type => 'mtime'
  }
```

I am getting an error stating the following:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter matches failed on Tidy[filebeat_lock]: Tidy can't use matches with recurse 0, false, or undef
```

The entity I want to cleanup is a file not a directory. So, why is the error showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entity I want to cleanup is a file not a directory. So, why is the error showing up?

You're telling Puppet that the entity you want to clean up is the directory `/var/lib/beat`.  That's what the `path` parameter designates if you specify it, or what the the resource title designates if you don't explicitly specify the `path` parameter.  At the same time, you have not provided a value for the `recurse` parameter, so the resource defaults to non-recursive, as if you had specified `recurse => false`.  It doesn't make sense to use `matches` in this context, where you've already specified exactly which file is to be managed.

There is a variety of ways to spell it, but the simplest way to express what you seem actually to want would be this:

```
tidy { '/var/lib/beat/run.lock':
  age  => '8h',
  type => 'mtime'
}
```

If you prefer to be able to refer to this resource elsewhere as `Tidy['beat_lock']` then you might instead say

```
tidy { 'beat_lock':
  path => '/var/lib/beat/run.lock',
  age  => '8h',
  type => 'mtime'
}
```

I don't see much reason to introduce an alias, however, and you certainly don't need one that's the same as the resource title.  I don't have any aliases declared anywhere in my own manifest set, and I don't recommend their use.